# ImageButton image not updating

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I got a ImageButton which should be updated when I press a button.
The onClick event gets triggerd, and I think the image itself gets updated (because the BitmapDrawable @id changes).

Here's my code

```
public void gotoBasicControls(View view) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    bottomButtonRemote.setImageResource(R.drawable.remote_selected_icon_transparent);
    bottomButtonRemoteText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAppOrange));
}
```

And here's my xml

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TableRow>
    <ImageButton
        android:maxHeight="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomRemote"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:onClick="gotoBasicControls"
        android:src="@drawable/remote_icon_transparent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomScoreboard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:onClick="gotoScoreboard"
        android:src="@drawable/scoreboard_icon_transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:maxHeight="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomStopwatch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="13dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:onClick="gotoStopwatch"
        android:src="@drawable/stopwatch_icon_transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:maxHeight="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomSettings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="gotoSettings"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_icon_transparent" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Basic"
        android:id="@+id/bottomRemoteText"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView android:text="Scoreboard"
        android:id="@+id/bottomScoreboardText"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView android:text="Stopwatch"
        android:id="@+id/bottomStopwatchText"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView android:text="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/bottomSettingsText"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</TableRow>
```

I should also note that the setTextColor also doesn't work.

The things I've tried are:
Use a URI instead of a drawable.
Invalidate the button and the layout it is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void gotoBasicControls(View view) {

viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);  
((ImageButton)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.remote_selected_icon_transparent);
buttonText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAppOrange));
}
```